# Type hinting content of an array

Tags: php, arrays, type-hinting

I've got a method that accepts an array of rules as an argument.

```
public function setRule($name, Array $rules) { ... }
```

The passed in array should only contain objects that implement the `IRule` interface, but since I can't type hint the content of an array I would like to know if there's maybe another way of doing it?

I would highly appreciate examples with your answers.

Comment: how about change the method signature to take a RuleList object, which expects only objects that implement IRule

Comment: In PHP array type cannot be designated to just 1 sub type. So your typehinting wish can also not be done. Even after validating your array, you can still put in other types.

Comment: There is [__arrayof__ RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrayof), which, however, was rejected. May be stars will roll a better dice next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible in the function header, but you can do `instanceof` checks later on.

Example:

```
foreach ($rules as $r) {
  if ($r instanceof IRule) {
    do_something();
  } else {
    raise_error();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most people now will suggest to check the Array right when you are inside the method, but better try this way;

Implement an [Iterator](http://php.net/iterator) (this is a class that can be used like an array, with `foreach` for example), and pass this iterator to your class:

```
class IRuleIterator implements Iterator {
    private $var = array();

    public function __construct($array) {
        if (is_array($array)) {
            $this->var = $array;
        }
    }

    public function add($element) {
        $this->var[] = $element;
        return $this;
    }

    public function rewind() {
        reset($this->var);
        return $this;
    }

    public function current() {
        return current($this->var);
    }

    public function key() {
        return key($this->var);
    }

    public function next() {
        return next($this->var);
    }

    public function valid() {
        return ($this->current() instanceof IRule);
    }
}
```

Then your function:

```
public function setRule($name, IRuleIterator $rules) { /* ... */ }
```

You can find a full list of those "special PHP objects" which can be implemented here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php

The `ArrayIterator` would be even better for your purpose. There are lots of nice things in the SPL, have a look at it :)

Comment: Nice idea! But you will have to refactor your code and change every occurence of an rules array.

Comment: What's the difference in functionality between the foreach and your solution?

Comment: Mine is faster, because the iterator can be implemented to only hold `IRule` objects, and you don't have to worry about the elements. It's also cleaner in OOP scope.

Comment: `public function add(IRule $element) {` for example.